# Customize html pages wordpress login and registration

Tags: php, html, wordpress, authentication

I want to make a private and customize wordpress login screen, registration and password recovery.

I do not want to use any plugin and wanted to do everything in funtions.php topic since I'm building a theme from scratch. I found tutorials with features such as logos add_action but only modify or add css. For example: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/customizing-the-wordpress-admin-the-login-screen--wp-33035

I want to change the structure of the html code and registration login to customize it.

A greeting and thanks.

Comment: What have you done already?

Comment: you could just edit the wp-login.php which handles this. you will find the html markup there. don't know if this will come along with updating issues since this hasn't anything to do with your theme. maybe it would be a better idea to create a custom login page.

Comment: `wp-login.php` is part of the Wordpress core, so I wouldn't really advise editing this.

Comment: What I have done for now is what the tutorial tuts +.
Nick R is right wp-login forms the core of wordpress, so if I edit this, the update will overwrite.

What I want, besides customizing the css is to customize the html code.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done for now is what the tutorial tuts +.
Nick R is right wp-login forms the core of wordpress, so if I edit this, the update will overwrite.

What I want, besides customizing the css is to customize the html code.